# Как снять задачу в java

Tags: java

Есть функция запуска таймера.

```
 new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {...}}, 1000, 1000);
```

Как остановить этот таймер по onClick кнопки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе, в котором выполняется данный код (скорее всего JFrame либо какой-нибудь фасад или обертка, которую вы так или иначе вызовите в JFrame), определить поле:

```
private Timer timer;
```

По хорошему, лучше всего создать объект этого класса вне вашего класса, а потом внедрить его, например, через конструктор (см. принцип инверсии зависимостей) или set метод:

```
public void setTimer(Timer timer){
    this.timer = timer;
}
```

и вызов (условный, конечно):

```
Timer timer = new Timer;

YouClass youClass = new YouClass();
youClass.setTimer(timer);
```

и внутри вашего класса определите два приватных метода:

```
private void initTimer(){

    if (timer == null) {throw new NullPointerException("init field \"timer\" first"); }

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

и

```
private void cancelTimer(){
    timer.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сохраните ссылку на созданный таймер, когда нужно остановить используйте метод [cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: Сохранить ссылку, это как? Можно пример?

Comment: Вы же программируете, не знаете, как сохранить созданный объект в переменной или в поле класса? Странные вопросы задаете.

Comment: Я только начал учиться JAVA. Да, я не знаю основ, не знаю элементарных вещей. Осваиваю по мере возможностей. Живу в глухой деревне с очень медленным интернетом, поэтому не все могу скачать чтобы быстрей учиться. Кстати, может посоветуете, литературу, где написано более менее доступным языком. Буду благодарен.

Comment: @kaaa: Поищите по сайту ([лучше гуглом](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+книги+site:hashcode.ru)), на вопрос о книгах отвечалось много раз.

Обязательно почитайте книги, без этого вы будете тыкаться в проблемы каждый раз. Не пожалейте месяца, это может оказаться лучшим вложением времени за всю жизнь.